# Adding code snippet to a HTML page made using Tailwind CSS

Tags: python, html, code-snippets, tailwind-css

I am making an HTML page using Tailwind CSS and want to add (python) code snippets to it. is there a way to do it?

Comment: what did you try first?

Comment: You can express any of code formats by Markdown editor in your HTML code. And if you want to make with Python, then this package is a bit popular. check this https://pypi.org/project/Markdown/

Comment: @Etienne I tried adding my code (to HTML) using the <code> tags but they don't work like usual thanks to Tailwind CSS.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: @KarlHill I want to know if there is any way to add python code snippets to a HTML page. That's it. I don't see the point of adding a "Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"